# Transition to a specific tab of a tab bar controller on button tap

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to achieve this functionality: on my log in screen (with username, password, and "log in" button), once the user clicks the "log in" button, it will go to the Tab Bar Controller and to the first view of it, titled Dashboard, automatically. Then the user can click the second tab, or third, to go to "Servers" or "My Account" tab if he/she wants to.

Essentially, I want it so that the first screen when the user opens the app, is the login screen, then after successfully logging in, they go to the Tab Bar Controller where they can pick which tab they want to go in or stay in the first one. Is this possible?

A part of my storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to present the login controller from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab. Do this with animation set to NO, and the login controller will be the first thing the user sees. When the user successfully logs in, dismiss the modal view controller, and you'll be back to the tab bar controller in the first tab.

Comment: How would I dismiss the modal view controller? I managed to present it.

Comment: @user2638403, [self presentViewController:login animated:NO completion:nil]; You would also want to put some logic in that method to determine whether the user is logged in or not, and only do the presentation if not.

Comment: Thanks, and as for dismissing it?

Comment: @user2638403, [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; I changed my last comment -- the animation should be NO for the presentation. This is really, really basic view controller stuff that you should know -- you need read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, yea I plan on very soon. Now it runs in an 'infinite loop' of sorts, but I assume that's because on my parent view it doesn't check if I am logged in or not and therefore just re-opens the login view?

Comment: @user2638403, yes, that's what will happen if you don't check for the logged in status.